# PHP 7 and SOAP WSDL with SSL error

Tags: php, ssl, soap, wsdl

I'm using Wsdl2PhpGenerator to create my soap client; was was working fine with PHP v5.4, but now I've upgraded to PHP 7 I get an error:

> Uncaught SoapFault: SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://sussexbedcentre.retailsystem.net/services/v2/GetCatalog.asmx?WSDL' : failed to load external entity

I have tried:

- Connecting to a non SSL soap service - worked fine, so must be the SSL.
- Every ssl_method
- soap.wsdl_cache_enabled, soap.wsdl_cache_ttl, soap.wsdl_cache all set to 0
- Verified openssl, soap, xmlrpc php extensions all loaded ok
- PEM file and passphrase worked fine under PHP 5.4

Any ideas what else I can try to get to the bottom of this?

Code I'm using is:

```
    $cert = 'rs_ssl.pem';

$generator = new \Wsdl2PhpGenerator\Generator();
$generator->generate(
    new \Wsdl2PhpGenerator\Config(array(
        'inputFile' => 'https://sussexbedcentre.retailsystem.net/services/v2/GetCatalog.asmx?WSDL',
        'outputDir' => 'soapclass/',
        'soapClientOptions' => array(
            'local_cert'    => $cert,
            'passphrase' => '*******',
            'connection_timeout' => 60,
            'trace' => 1,
            'soap_version'   => SOAP_1_2
        )
    ))
);
```

If I switch back to PHP 5.4 with the same code it works fine.

Thanks!